# Data Studio and STDDEV

Tags: looker-studio

Google Data Studio has a function to calculate the standard deviation for a metric. The example given in the tooltip is `STDDEV(pageviews)`.

[image]

However this results in an error "re-aggregation of metrics not supported" , and indeed the tooltip says that the used field cannot be result of an aggregation. However in Data Studio "[metrics always have an aggregation type](http://%20metrics%20always%20have%20an%20aggregation%20type)".

Given that, I do not understand how STDEV is to be used. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, the warning you are getting is because it thinks you are trying to get the standard deviation of a metric which has already had an aggregation method applied, e.g. STDDEV(SUM(pageviews)).

Check to make sure no aggregation has already been applied to that particular metric first. If it has you can try duplicating the metric and removing the aggregation on the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. But no, that's not it - I used the actual example from the tooltip and documentation.

Comment: However in Data Studio "metrics always have an aggregation type". This used to be true but you no longer have to specify an aggregation type and can leave it as 'None'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Datastudio only accepts dimensions (the green fields) for STDEV, not metrics (the blue fields).

Comment: it doesn't look like the answer, try to avoid giving a comment. once you will get the privilege to comment anywhere (that comes after getting some points here) then you can comment something like this. it makes answers more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I don't see why this isn't the answer? The question is how STDEV is to be used because it doesn't work on pageviews; the answer is that STDEV only works on dimensions (pageviews is a metric). Could you please explain why this doesn't answer the question?